# how to merge a groupby output (series) back to the dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I've a data frame (portfolios) like this

```
Date    ReturnonEquity
31-Jan-10   0.67
31-Jan-10   1.00
31-Jan-10   0.49
31-Jan-10   0.15
28-Feb-10   0.80
28-Feb-10   0.08
28-Feb-10   0.54
28-Feb-10   0.77
```

I calculated the winsorized Roe for every date -

```
portfolios.groupby(by='Date')['ROE'].apply(lambda x: zscore(mstats.winsorize(x[~np.isnan(x)],0.03)))
```

which outputs a series like this (ignore values)

```
2010-01-31   [0.67, 1.00, 0.49, 0.15]
2010-02-28    [0.80, 0.08, 0.54, 0.77]
```

how do i put the z-scores back in the portfolios as a new column (join creates the columns with the array, not like a continuous values)

Date    ReturnonEquity  RoE_winsorized

```
31-Jan-10   0.67              0.67
31-Jan-10   1.00              1.00
31-Jan-10   0.49              0.49
31-Jan-10   0.15              0.15
28-Feb-10   0.80              0.80
28-Feb-10   0.08              0.08
28-Feb-10   0.54              0.54
28-Feb-10   0.77              0.77
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Without knowing the details of your winsorized function, do you want `groupby.transform`?  Then you could do `df['roe'] = df.groupby(...).transform(...)`

Comment: yes. i should indeed use transform. thank you for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Use transform](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#transformation) (instead of apply), as chrisb suggests, and assign the result to `portfolios[columname]`:

```
In [42]: portfolios['windsorized'] = portfolios.groupby(by='Date')['ROE'].transform(lambda x: (stats.zscore(mstats.winsorize(x[~np.isnan(x)],0.03))))

In [43]: portfolios
Out[43]: 
        Date   ROE  windsorized
0 2010-01-31  0.67     0.301112
1 2010-01-31  1.00     1.375348
2 2010-01-31  0.49    -0.284835
3 2010-01-31  0.15    -1.391624
4 2010-02-28  0.80     0.876605
5 2010-02-28  0.08    -1.623022
6 2010-02-28  0.54    -0.026038
7 2010-02-28  0.77     0.772454
```